# How to convert Object with nested arrays to array of flat objects?

Tags: javascript

I have object with array of options. On each option I need to create flat object. Like so

```
name: 'win10',
        architectures: ['x64', 'x86'],
        languages: ['en', 'ru'],
```

Transforms into:

```
[
{ name: 'win10',
        architectures 'x64',
        languages: 'en',
}, {
name: 'win10',
        architectures:  'x86',
        languages: 'ru',
}, {
name: 'win10',
        architectures: 'x64',
        languages: 'en',
}, {
name: 'win10',
        architectures: 'x86',
        languages: 'ru',
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```js
let input = {
        name: 'win10',
        architectures: ['x64', 'x86'],
        languages: ['en', 'ru']
};

function flatten(system) {
        let output = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < system.architectures.length; i++) {
                const arch = system.architectures[i];
                for (let j = 0; j < system.languages.length; j++) {
                        const lang = system.languages[j];
                        output = [...output, {
                                name: system.name,
                                architectures: arch,
                                language: lang
                        }];
                }
        }
        return output;
}

const output = flatten(input);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Is there any reason to create a new array in every loop with `output = [...output, {..}]` instead of simply doing `output.push()`?

Comment: Both approaches are valid, `output = [...output, {..}]` unpacks the output array and appends the object to it. You can choose `.push()` if you prefer it

Comment: But a new array is being created in every iteration and another array is being spread for no reason. It makes sense doing something like react where mutating the array isn't allowed. If it is being assigned back to the `ouptut` variable, this is completely pointless

Comment: As I've said, you can choose any of them. It's up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach

```
var x = { name: 'win10',
        architectures: ['x64', 'x86'],
        languages: ['en', 'ru'] }
var k = [];
 x.architectures.forEach(p => {
 x.languages.forEach((y => {
    k.push({name: x.name, architectures:p,languages:y})
  }))
})

console.log(k)
```

Comment: This is almost the same as my approach but you must note that `forEach` is waaaay slower than `for() {...}`

Comment: It depends on the array size, always go with the latest syntax

Comment: It's not as important in this example but when going for performance, you should keep that in mind, the speedup is 150-200% (from my tests)

Comment: I agree for loop is much faster than forEach but syntax wise forEach is cleaner more readability and chances of accidental errors are less
If you are interested to know more about forEach and for you can check this doc
https://alligator.io/js/foreach-vs-for-loops/

Comment: And I agree forEach is quite a bit cleaner. Thanks for the great document on the differences!